# Google Adwords API + Python Certificate Verify Field

Tags: python, django, google-api

I have this code using the python google ads api.
I return this error:

```
    oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token)
    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(developer_token, oauth2_client, user_agent,client_customer_id=client_customer_id)
    customer_service = adwords_client.GetService('CustomerService',version='v201702')
    customers = customer_service.getCustomers()
```

Comment: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>

Comment: I think it would help if you posted the version of Python you are using, as well as the names and versions of any external libraries (e.g. `adwords`) that you are using.

Comment: Martery, Thanks for your comment, I did solve the problem running the the file: Install Certificates.command into the folder Python files.